# Meaning of "on a variety of tasks"

Tags: phrase-meaning, prepositional-phrases

> Go over the documents which will be reviewed by Ms. Gao. The documents are **on
>   a variety of tasks** where I need her input in order to complete.

What does "on a variety of tasks " mean? I know the meaning of each word, but not the overall meaning of the words together.

Comment: There is no combination: the subject(s) of the documents is/are several ("a variety of") different tasks.

Comment: I'm not sure about the source of your confusion, because as you said, you know the meaning of each word. I guess two possibilities: a) you may know *variety*, but not in this sense (see stangdon's answers below), or b) you try to read *"on a variety of tasks"* as one phrase, which is not technically incorrect, but it suggests that you might forget to read this *on* as a plain *on* (i.e., *The books are on the table*; there's nothing special about this *on*).

Comment: your are right. i regarded "on" and other words  together. it's clear now. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything here has its literal dictionary definition (although some of the words have many meanings).

On: [in connection or association with](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/on).
A variety: [a number of different kinds of things](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/variety).
Of: [relating or belonging to](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/of).
Task: [a piece of work](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/task).

So the documents were *related to a number of different kinds of work*.

Comment: i missunderstood "on" .  Thank you very much for your explaination.

Answer (score 1):

"On" in this example is used as a synonym of "about" or "relating to".

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/on) gives the relevant definition of on as:

> Having (the thing mentioned) as a topic; about:

In your example the thing mentioned is the tasks. So "The documents are on a variety of tasks" could be written "The documents are **about** a variety of tasks" instead with no change in meaning.